# install/access executable for existing docker container

Tags: docker

I want to run an executable and all of its libraries from within my container. How do I do that?

For my Ubuntu 14.04 server, I can do `sudo apt-get install tetex-base tetex-bin`

In this case, however, someone already set up a docker container for me, and I need to be able to run the program from within the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working with

```
docker exec -it containerName apt-get install tetex-base tetex-bin
```

See [docs](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/exec/).